# Replacement for uploadify

Tags: java, uploadify

I am doing asynchronous file upload using uploadify. Everything works fine but it is not working in certain browsers, like firefox.

I am using spring multipartrequest to get the file in the controller. What would be the best replacement for uploadify or how do I fix the firefox issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You kind of need to be more specific if you are looking to resolve the issue with Firefox. What isnt working? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Sorry i am replying too late, the problem is that the flash content of uploadify doesnt execute so it becomes a normal browse button. I tried it in many systems but this problem is persisting.Also no error is shown

Comment: Are you looking for the error in firebug? If you are using the latest version of Firefox, a flash bug was introduced in the last couple versions which I have heard they are looking into fixing. I dont think the problem is with uploadify itself.

Comment: The HTML5 version of uploadify (uploadifive) works on all the latest HTML 5 compliant browsers (including Firefox). We switch dynamically between the two uploaders to cover most current browsers. There is a small cost for uploadifive (and it has subtle difference to uploadify you need to look out for)